# React error - A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So this is happening in a modal component of mine and it happens where I begin to type into any input. In the modal component I have my state values pre-defined like so:

```
    const [contactPerson, setContactPerson] = useState('')
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date().toISOString())
    const [emailTo, setEmailTo] = useState('')
    const [details, setDetails] = useState('')
    const [outcome, setOutcome] = useState('')
    const [followUp, setFollowUp] = useState('')
    const [newCall, setNewCall] = useState(false)
    const [diaryNewCallDate, setDiaryNewCallDate] = useState('')
    const [diaryNewCallDetails, setDiaryNewCallDetails] = useState('')
```

And I have 2 useEffects, the first is to check if `props.id` is set, then it means we are editing an "email" and we need to dispatch the action to get the email, if not, we set the values of the inputs to empty to prepare for a new "email" being added.

The second useEffect is to check if the `email` value is set, I have a useSelector getting the value if the action is called. If it is set, then I set the values of the state to the values in the `email`.

Below is all of the code until the return statement. In all my inputs I have the usual `value={state} onChange={e => setState(e.target.value)}`

```
   const [contactPerson, setContactPerson] = useState('')
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date().toISOString())
    const [emailTo, setEmailTo] = useState('')
    const [details, setDetails] = useState('')
    const [outcome, setOutcome] = useState('')
    const [followUp, setFollowUp] = useState('')
    const [newCall, setNewCall] = useState(false)
    const [diaryNewCallDate, setDiaryNewCallDate] = useState('')
    const [diaryNewCallDetails, setDiaryNewCallDetails] = useState('')

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const emailDetails = useSelector(state => state.emailDetails)
    const { loading, error, email } = emailDetails

    const submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        
        props.onSave(contactPerson, date, emailTo, details, outcome, followUp, diaryNewCallDate, diaryNewCallDetails)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!!props.id) {
            dispatch(getEmailDetails(props.id))
        } else {
            setContactPerson('')
            setDate(new Date().toISOString())
            setEmailTo('')
            setDetails('')
            setOutcome('')
            setFollowUp('')
            setNewCall(false)
            setDiaryNewCallDate('')
            setDiaryNewCallDetails('')
        }
    }, [props.id, dispatch])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(email) {
            setContactPerson(email.contact_person)
            setDate(email.date)
            setEmailTo(email.email_to)
            setDetails(email.details)
            setOutcome(email.outcome)
            setFollowUp(email.follow_up)

            if(email.diary_new_call) {
                setNewCall(true)
                setDiaryNewCallDate(email.diary_new_call.date)
                setDiaryNewCallDetails(email.diary_new_call.details)
            }
        }
    }, [email])
```

Comment: Does the error at least tell you which input is changing from uncontrolled to controlled? Basically the error is telling you that an input has changed from having an `undefined`|`null` value to a defined value. [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DrewReese Unfortunately not, this is the error in its entirety `component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.`